# Caption using Tables

Tags: tables

I am having a problem using captions with Tables. My caption seems to have a weird border so it creates a new line using only one or two words when trying to caption a table.

Here is the code I am using and a picture of the problem. Any help is much appreciated on how to make my borders for the caption run the full length of the table.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\parbox{.2\linewidth}{
\centering
\label{dt1}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ccc}
&Upward Balancing  &Downward Balancing\\
\hline
Surplus imbalance &Elspot price & (BM-)  \\
Deficit imbalance &(BM+)         & Elspot price \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Imbalance Prices for Producers}
}
\end{table}
```

[image: Caption not running length of Table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Why are you encasing all material inside the `table` environment in a `\parbox{.2\linewidth}{...}` "wrapper"? The result of such a setup is that the `tabular` material will use the minimally necessary space -- which is evidently a lot more than `0.2\linewidth`! -- while the argument of `\caption` will be forced into a very narrow box.

Comment: A separate comment: `\label` must come after, not before, `\caption` if you intend to be able to cross-reference the `table` elsewhere in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Don't encase the contents of the `table` environment in a `\parbox` "wrapper", especially not one that's manifestly too narrow to contain the `tabular` material. All you will achieve is to constrain the width of the caption material.
- If you wish to be able to cross-reference the `table` in question, place the `\label` statement *after*, not before, the `\caption` statement. (If you have no plans to create cross-references using LaTeX's machinery, you may as well omit the `\label` statement.)
- Consider loading the `booktabs` package and replacing the two generic-LaTeX `\hline` directives with `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` instructions. That'll lead to much-improved spacing above and below the rules. Additionally, you may want to provide (a lot) more structure to the header material, to make it easier for your readers to "grasp" what the tabular material is all about.

The following screenshot shows both your original table (with the "cramped" caption) as well as one that implements the preceding suggestions.

There's also an attempt to cross-reference both `table` environments; observe that the first cross-reference fails because the `\label` was placed before `\caption`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % choose a suitable document class
\usepackage{float,booktabs,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent \emph{Line to illustrate width of textblock}:
\hrule 

\bigskip\noindent
\textcolor{red}{First, the original version:}
\begin{table}[H]
\parbox{.2\linewidth}{%
\centering
\label{dt1}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ccc}
&Upward Balancing  &Downward Balancing\\
\hline
Surplus imbalance &Elspot price & (BM-)  \\
Deficit imbalance &(BM+)         & Elspot price \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Original version}
}
\end{table}

\bigskip\noindent
\textcolor{red}{Now the modified version:}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\toprule
Type of imbalance & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Direction of balancing}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
& Upward & Downward \\
\midrule
Surplus & Elspot price       & (BM$-$)  \\
Deficit & (BM$+$)            & Elspot price \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Modified version} \label{dt2}
\end{table}

\noindent
Cross-references to Tables \ref{dt1} and \ref{dt2}---note the unfortunate ``gap'' where the first cross-reference should appear.
\end{document}
```